# Continuous function on a complex space that is holomorphic on the complement of a closed subspace

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex analytic space and $Y\subseteq X$ a closed complex subspace. Suppose that $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function that is holomorphic on $X\setminus Y$. Is $f$ holomorphic on $X$?

**Note.** This is true if $X$ is non-singular by the Riemann extension theorem.

Comment: No. Take $X\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $y^2=x^3$, $Y=\{(0,0)\} $. The map $\pi :\mathbb{C}\rightarrow X$ defined by $\pi (t)= (t^2,t^3)$ is a homeomorphism; the inverse function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and holomorphic on $X\smallsetminus Y$, but not on $X$.

Comment: @abx Thanks, that's a good counterexample! Do you expect the answer to change if $Y$ is of sufficiently large codimension?

Comment: see thm. 1B, chap 8, Whitney's Complex Analytic Varieties, p. 251, for some sufficient conditions when Y has high codimension, e.g. if X is a hypersurface, Y contains all singular points, and codimY ≥ 2.